# HTML content for button_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, button, twitter-bootstrap, button-to

I am currently using link_to:

```
<%= link_to edit_webcast_path(@webcast), :class => 'btn'  do %>
    <i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit Webcast
<% end %>
```

But I want to do the same with button_to, however button_to must have a first label argument passed to it or it will use the path as its label.

```
<%= button_to edit_webcast_path(@webcast), :class => 'btn'  do %>
    <i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit Webcast
<% end %>
```

... results in a button with a label that is the resolved edit_webcast_path(@webcast) path. In effect do seems to have no effect.

I have tried passing html directly as the first argument:

```
<%= button_to "<i class=\"icon-white icon-minus-sign \"></i> Edit Webcast".html_safe, webcast_path(@webcast), :class => 'btn'%>
```

But this results in a button with the label displaying part of the html string I pass in. Looking at the generated HTMl I can see that the contents of this first argument is placed in the input's value attribute and not inside the input itself.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails `button_to` generates a form with html `<input type="submit">` element , not `<button>` one. 
You can try to override it or write your own helper to generate `<button>` , take a [look at this example](http://pastebin.com/9sFvJDXD)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I should still be able to place an <i></i> tag inside an input element though shouldn't I?

Comment: You can't place html tags inside submit button, but can do it with `<button>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/83ktY/

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, button_to will try to do a post or put, so it is not actually a "regular" button, you can style your link to look and act like a button

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML inside a `button_to` element like this:

```
<%= button_to "New", new_articles_path do %>
  Create a <strong>new article</strong>
<% end %>
```

More info: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Answer (score -5):

You are doing it wrong. You are trying to add a unnecessary html element to control something that is the CSS job.

Instead just create  a class or Id for the button and add this to the css:

```
 .btn { padding-left:30px; background: url(pencil.png) no-repeat; }
```